# Import remote CSV file to MySQL database - script

Tags: mysql, import

In RHEL server, I have a CSV file containing varchar data as below and these .csv files being uploade every day at 07:30 A.M.:

```
blacklist_04072020.csv
blacklist_05072020.csv
blacklist_06072020.csv
```

This is the content of the file:

```
905557537356
905541160424
905557528812
905541158733
905557538205
905541162304
905541165328
905541159753
905541165224
905557534030
905557536964
905541162993
905557532024
905541156924
905557523055
905541168700
905541168374
905557527431
905541164440
905557541777
905557549542
905551789775
905557530328
905539319755
905539156905
905539213849
905557514304
905557532169
905557528952
905551783471
905053807307
905347323697
905523069140
905364083304
905346646189
905344025276
905443706621
905396605566
905433556349
905396975953
905396495913
905529405079
905510737258
```

So I want to load all these numbers into my blacklist table in remote MySQL database.
The blacklist table contains `msisdn (VARCHAR,20)`, `REASON(SET AS 0)`, `CREATION_TIME (UPLOADING_TIME)`.

So I need a proper bash script for this, can you help me please?

Comment: If this CSV files are accessible from the host where MySQL is installed using some network path (\\host\resource\directory\filename.csv) then you may use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE for importing without any external (bash) script from SP executed in event.

Comment: Hello, actually I need bash script, I don't wanna add any event on db-server.

Comment: Show us what you have tried first. I can't see anything related to bash here